# clang-format: align consecutive declarations ignoring *

Tags: c++, clang-format

Using clang-format style options

```
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
PointerAlignment: "Right"
```

I get the following code style

```
int         aaaa = 12;
long        *b = nullptr;
std::string ccc = "23";
```

How to set clang-format style options so I get the following code style, consecutive declarations there are aligned by the variable names ignoring asterisk?

```
int         aaaa = 12;
long       *b = nullptr;
std::string ccc = "23";
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `long *b = ...;` is C-style declaration. `long* b = ...;` is C++ style declaration.

Comment: if you are using version control then one version is worse than the other. What if you add a `std::vector<double>` ? Then all lines in the block will have to change, just saying...

Comment: @user463035818 Don't tell me that. It's a legacy code style of my company that I must use in new code too.

Comment: oh in that case I am really sorry for you.

Comment: Can't you change the style when you have clang-format? (Or convince some people)

Comment: @JVApen I try it, but unsuccessfully at this moment.

Comment: Once you are at the same wave length about the advantages compared to disadvantages, you can get a lot of change. I've managed to change the braces